# Creating a Graph Collection with an existing CosmosDB Account

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I have an existing CosmosDB Account which was originally set up for the SQL api. I would like to create a graph but keep/manage it under the same database account.

I would like to use the Gremlin.Net sdk which (if I understand properly) requires the 'https://my-account.gremlin.cosmosdb.azure.com:443/' endpoint.  Do all collections have this endpoint, or only collections created with an account targeting the gremlin api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way of doing this would be

1. Create a new Graph account ( this will create the required gremlin server endpoint)
2. Migrate existing data using graph bulk executor.

Jayanta